# Как удалить сообщение бота при нажатии на inline кнопку?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Хочу реализовать удаления сообщение бота при нажатии на inline кнопку в публичном чате, но возникает ошибка:

```
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound: Message to delete not found
```

Вот код

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('текст', reply_markup=urlkb)

urlkb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='принять', callback_data='test'))

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="test")
async def test_call(message: types.Message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Обращаешься к `callback_query.message` и удаляешь. В message у тебя будет сообщение в котором была инлайн кнопка на которую нажали.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="test")
async def test_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.delete()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]