# Как можно сделать удаления сообщения, при нажатии на inline кнопку Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Телеграмм бот написан на библиотеке Aiogram, пытаюсь удалить сообщение при нажатии на Inline кнопку, которая находится у сообщения, но при попытке это сделать, выдаёт ошибку. Пытался сделать такой вариант:

```
Close = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅ Пометить как выполненный', callback_data='close'))
```

Отправляю сообщение:

```
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пример"), reply_markup=Close)
```

И, сообственно, сама функция в которой возникает ошибка (Handler'ы я регистрирую, тут всё хорошо)

```
async def closeReply(callback : types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer("✅ Вопрос помечен как выполненный")
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.from_user.message_id)
```

Ошибка:

```
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Как мне удалить сообщение?

Comment: NameError означает обращение к отсутствующей переменной

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить сообщение бота при нажатии на inline кнопку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359081/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-inline-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

В функции closeReply вы принимаете аргумент callback. Тогда почему ты пишешь `message.chat.id`? Может `callback.message.message_id` или `callback.id`?
Попробуйте такой вариант:
[image: Создание кнопки]
[image: Создание обработчика (handler)]
[image: Просто вывод клавиатуры с помощью команды /start]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1 ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 правильно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

извините за подчёркнутое ибо делал на скорую руку

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]